# Disabling other comboxes if one is filled

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written part of the code to disable comboxes. But looking at this, it doesn't feel like a good and optimal way to do it (it works, but it does not feel right).

I have created a list of combobox objects.

```
            InputCheck.Add(PAR_G_P_19_M);
            InputCheck.Add(PAR_G_P_20_M);
            InputCheck.Add(PAR_G_P_21_M);
            InputCheck.Add(PAR_G_P_25_M);
```

And if the selected index changes, it uses the function

```
            foreach (ComboBox combo in InputCheck) 
            {
                combo.SelectedIndexChanged += Check;
            }
```

And now my main problem. To my current knowledge, I have writen disabling comboboxes this way.

```
            if (PAR_G_P_19_M.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                PAR_G_P_19_M.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_20_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_21_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_25_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (PAR_G_P_20_M.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                PAR_G_P_19_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_20_M.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_21_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_25_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (PAR_G_P_21_M.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                PAR_G_P_19_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_20_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Enabled = false;

                PAR_G_P_21_M.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_25_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (PAR_G_P_25_M.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                PAR_G_P_19_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_20_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_21_M.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Text = "0";
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Enabled = false;
                PAR_G_P_25_M.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                PAR_G_P_19_M.Enabled = true;
                PAR_G_P_19_A.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_20_M.Enabled = true;
                PAR_G_P_20_A.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_21_M.Enabled = true;
                PAR_G_P_21_A.Enabled = true;

                PAR_G_P_25_M.Enabled = true;
                PAR_G_P_25_A.Enabled = true;

            }
```

If one combobox has value after trigger selectedindexchange, rest is disabled

How can this function be written better? The way i did it feels brute-forced.

Comment: Why don't you loop over `InputCheck` and disable everything that wasn't selected?

Comment: "And if the selected index changes, it uses the function". It sounds like you call the next code block every time. Connecting the event should be done once. Naming implies you have pairs of controls, like Combobox and Textbox that have interacting logic. Think about putting those in usercontrols and putting that logic into there also. That will simplify code. Naming of your controls (especially th enumbering) also implies that you have way to many on controls on a single form. Breaking it down into reusable usercontrols may help also. Think about better naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's organize the controls better and include the textboxes in the input check variable as well by using tuples. This will allow us to handle them in a loop as well. We make it an array, since its size will never change.

```cs
private (ComboBox CB, TextBox TB)[] _inputCheck;
```

In the form constructor we initialize:

```cs
InitializeComponent();

_inputCheck = new[] {
    (PAR_G_P_19_M, PAR_G_P_19_A),
    (PAR_G_P_20_M, PAR_G_P_20_A),
    (PAR_G_P_21_M, PAR_G_P_21_A),
    (PAR_G_P_25_M, PAR_G_P_25_A)
};

foreach (var item in _inputCheck) {
    item.CB.SelectedIndexChanged += Check;
}
```

The event handler now uses loops:

```cs
private void Check(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var currentCombo = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (currentCombo.SelectedIndex > 0) {
        foreach (var (CB, TB) in _inputCheck) {
            if (CB == currentCombo) {
                TB.Enabled = true;
            } else {
                CB.Enabled = false;
                TB.Enabled = false;
                TB.Text = "0";
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach (var (CB, TB) in _inputCheck) {
            CB.Enabled = true;
            TB.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about tuples here

- [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

Comment: Thank you very much. It work perfectly and looks very good. You have even take care of textboxes i didnt write in desrciption. I will read about tuples as it is new thing for(thank you for showing me this). The rest of code is clear

Comment: Okay, the `_checking` variable was not required after all, since you are setting the Text of a TextBox, not a ComboBox. It took me a while to realize that the `_A` controls are TextBoxes.

Comment: I have failed to metion that the pairs of combobox and textbox are in group of 4. So i  added group definition for them.
' _inputCheck = new[] 
            {
                (PAR_G_P_19_M, PAR_G_P_19_A,1),
                (PAR_G_P_20_M, PAR_G_P_20_A,1),
                (PAR_G_P_21_M, PAR_G_P_21_A,1),
                (PAR_G_P_25_M, PAR_G_P_25_A,1),
                (PAR_G_P_22_M, PAR_G_P_22_A,2),'
etc.
Then i have added arguments for ifs in fuctions